# Extremely long run time for MFA command in R. Is it the code, data too long or just R?

Tags: r, csv, factor-analysis

Photo of data.table in R studio

[image]

I am trying to run a Multiple Factor Analysis on R for over 100,000 lines (# of villages) on about 30 columns of variables. This is my line of code:

```
HH_amenities <- read.csv("Treated/HH_treated.csv")

res.mfa <- MFA(HH_amenities,
               group = c(3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4, 2, 2),
               type = c("s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s", "s"),
               name.group = c("number_rooms","number_pp", "ownership", "drinking", "lighting", "defecation", "drainage", "cooking", "amenities", "living_condition", "drinking_location"),
               num.group.sup = NULL, graph = FALSE)
```

As I run the `MFA` command I get no error notifications, it just takes an extremely long amount of time to the point where I eventually have to give click to the stop button. 
Is there an error with my code, is my dataset too large or should I be changing something in my settings? 
Thanks

Comment: I think you want to change "As I run the `res.mfa` command..." to "As I run the `MFA` command...". `res.mfa` is a variable in your code, not a command; `MFA` is the command.

Comment: Very true, edited

Comment: Have you tried with a subset of your data?

Comment: Good idea, so I've just tried it with only 400 rows and it worked. It would therefore seem that my original dataset is too large but it is only 32mb... I've seen on other posts that R can easily process up to 2GB data frames

Comment: @inouevongseguy I don't think this is about R so much and it is likely more about the `MFA` function in the `FactoMineR` package (you should include a `library(FactoMineR)` in your code). I suspect that the `MFA` function has not been optimized for speed. Have you looked into other packages that do multi factor analysis ?

Comment: If you can't find an answer in your search, you could reach out to the maintainers of `FactoMineR`.

Comment: @steveb I'm not sure how exactly I would integrate library(FactoMineR) into  the code. I tried the following but it didn't give the intended                     
result res.mfa <- library(FactoMineR(MFA(HH_amenities, ....

Comment: I mean put `library(FactoMineR)` at the beginning of your code.

Comment: @inouevongseguy FYI, I mean include the `library(FactoMineR)` in your code for completeness of the question, it won't solve your problem.